# First Order Equations and characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, characteristics

I am trying to solve

$u_t +x^2 u_x = 0\hspace{0.5 cm} x>0, t\in \mathbb{R}$
$u(0,t)=g(t)\hspace{0.5 cm} t\in \mathbb{R}$

and by the method of the characteristics I have found that it has as a general solution:
$u(x,t)=f(\frac{1}{x}+t)$

where $f$ is an arbitrary function. But I have no idea how to find the particular solution given the boundary condition.  Well, when I substitute $ x = 0 $ in the general solution the term $\frac{1}{x}$ is indeterminate.

tThen i think i'm doing something wrong.  They could tell me what I'm doing wrong or have a suggestion to solve the problem.  Thanks

Comment: First, it should be $u = \color{blue}{f}(x^{-1} \color{red}{+} t)$ for some arbitrary differentiable function $f$. And you haven't done anything wrong, what you have found is the general solution.

Comment: ooh right, my mistake was writing the solution in the forum, but I correct it right away.  But how could I find the solution in the boundary conditions, that is, in $u (0, t) = g (t)$ ?  This is where I have problems and I don't know how to proceed, I don't see clearly what I should do. Have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Note that $x=0$ is outside the domain of the function, so you can’t expect to use it as boundary data. Use $x=c$, where $c>0$ instead.